# How to actively avoid duplicate rows from the angle of the code not database?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I get a table called `tb_user_portrait` which saves customers' head portrait, its schema looks quite simple,

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_user_portrait` (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'custormer id',
    portrait_hash CHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'portrait image hash',
    is_valid TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'validation flag of this row',
    primary key(id)
)
```

I don't set any unique key, because customers may upload head portraits several times. However each user is supposed to have only one valid portrait(i.e. each of them could have only one `is_valid=1` record).

My code to deal with the uploading operation is simple too,

```
def upload(user_id, portrait_hash, is_valid=1):
    # find the last is_valid=1 records, and set invalid
    portrait = DBSession().query(UserPortrait).\
        filter(UserPortrait.user_id == user_id).\
        filter(UserPortrait.is_valid == 1).\
        scalar()
    if portrait:
        portrait.is_valid = 0
        DBSession().add(portrait)
    # create new valid portrait and save it to db
    new_portrait = UserPortrait(
        user_id=user_id,
        portrait_hash=portrait_hash,
        is_valid=is_valid)
    DBSession().add(new_portrait)
    DBSession().commit()
```

Although I firstly find out the valid record and set invalid, I always come across `MultipleRowsFound` and there're more than one records(`is_valid=1`) in the database.

By the way, I use **SQLAlchemy** and turn the `session.autoflush` on.

I'm wondering why it happens? Is there any best practice to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

From SQLAlchemy:

> autoflush – When True, all query operations will issue a flush() call to this Session before proceeding. This is a convenience feature so that flush() need not be called repeatedly in order for database queries to retrieve results. It’s typical that autoflush is used in conjunction with autocommit=False. In this scenario, explicit calls to flush() are rarely needed; you usually only need to call commit() (which flushes) to finalize changes.

So basically you don't commit your change to database, that's why it doesn't work and you have more than one record with `is_invalid = 1`.

Instead of turning on `session.autoflush` try to do it manually, so here:

```
...
if portrait:
    portrait.is_valid = 0
    DBSession().add(portrait)
    DBSession().flush() # <-- here

new_portrait = UserPortrait(
    user_id=user_id,
    portrait_hash=portrait_hash,
    is_valid=is_valid)
...
```

And if it still doesn't work, instead of:

```
    DBSession().flush()
```

just use:

```
    DBSession().commit()
```